Remove objects in a migration
I'm migrating from Drupal 7 to Drupal 10. Migration runs successfully as expected. However, when I run drush migrate:status, I got these errors:

[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_custom_block: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.boxes' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_file: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.files' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_filter_format: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.filter_formats' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_taxonomy_term: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.term_data' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_taxonomy_vocabulary: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_vocabulary_entity_display: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_vocabulary_entity_form_display: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_vocabulary_field: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT() AS "expression"
[error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_vocabulary_field_instance: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "expression"



Migration ID
Status
Total
Imported
Unprocessed




action_settings
Idle
1
0
0          >
Idle
1
block_content_entity_display
1
0          >
Idle
1
block_content_type
1
0          >
Idle
0
d6_block
215
215


d6_custom_block
Idle
N/A
0     >
N/A


d6_date_formats
Idle
0
0
0


d6_dblog_settings
Idle
1
0
1


d6_file
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d6_filter_format
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d6_menu
Idle
4
0
4


d6_menu_links
Idle
7
0
7


d6_node_setting_promote
Idle
4
0
4


d6_node_setting_status
Idle
4
0
4


d6_node_setting_sticky
Idle
4
0
4


d6_node_settings
Idle
1
0
1


d6_node_type
Idle
4
0
4


d6_system_cron
Idle
1
0
1


d6_system_date
Idle
1
0
1


d6_system_file
Idle
1
0
1


d6_system_performance
Idle
1
0
1


d6_taxonomy_term
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d6_taxonomy_vocabulary
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d6_upload_field
Idle
1
0
1


d6_user
Idle
7
0
7


d6_user_contact_settings
Idle
7
0
7


d6_user_mail
Idle
1
0
1


d6_user_picture_file
Idle
0
0
0


d6_user_role
Idle
4
0
4


d6_user_settings
Idle
1
0
1


d6_vocabulary_entity_display
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d6_vocabulary_entity_form_display
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d6_vocabulary_field
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d6_vocabulary_field_instance
Idle
N/A
0
N/A


d7_action
Idle
14
8
0


d7_block
Idle
215
8
0


d7_custom_block
Idle
2
2
0


d7_dblog_settings
Idle
1
1
0


d7_field
Idle
185
185
0


d7_field_formatter_settings
Idle
193
0
193


d7_field_instance
Idle
191
191
0


d7_field_instance_widget_settings
Idle
191
0
191


d7_file
Idle
14786
14745
38


d7_file_private
Idle
0
0
0


d7_filter_format
Idle
3
3
0


d7_filter_settings
Idle
1
1
0


d7_global_theme_settings
Idle
1
1
0


d7_image_settings
Idle
1
1
0


d7_image_styles
Idle
0
0
0


d7_menu
Idle
4
0
4


d7_menu_links
Idle
7
0
7


d7_node:page
Idle
1554
1550
4


d7_node:panel
Idle
0
0
0


d7_node_complete:page
Idle
1554
1550
4


d7_node_complete:panel
Idle
0
0
0


d7_node_revision:page
Idle
0
0
0


d7_node_revision:panel
Idle
0
0
0


d7_node_settings
Idle
1
1
0


d7_node_title_label
Idle
4
0
4


d7_node_type
Idle
4
4
0


d7_system_authorize
Idle
1
0
0


d7_system_cron
Idle
1
1
0


d7_system_date
Idle
1
1
0


d7_system_file
Idle
1
0
0


d7_system_mail
Idle
0
0
0


d7_system_performance
Idle
1
1
0


d7_taxonomy_term:category
Idle
30
30
0


d7_taxonomy_vocabulary
Idle
1
1
0


d7_theme_settings
Idle
2
0
2


d7_user
Idle
7
7
0


d7_user_flood
Idle
1
1
0


d7_user_mail
Idle
1
1
0


d7_user_role
Idle
4
4
0


d7_user_settings
Idle
1
1
0


d7_view_modes
Idle
2
0
2


file_settings
Idle
1
1
0


menu_settings
Idle
1
1
0


system_image
Idle
1
1
0


system_image_gd
Idle
1
1
0


system_logging
Idle
1
1
0


system_maintenance
Idle
1
1
0


system_rss
Idle
1
1
0


system_site
Idle
1
1
0


taxonomy_settings
Idle
1
1
0


text_settings
Idle
1
1
0


update_settings
Idle
1
1
0


user_picture_entity_display
Idle
1
1
0


user_picture_entity_form_display
Idle
1
1
0


user_picture_field
Idle
1
1
0


user_picture_field_instance
Idle
1
1
0




I don't care about those objects as they seem coming from an old Drupal 6 migration.
How can I remove those objects from migration so I don't have those error messages?

So you need to check your migration status using a tag or group so that D6 is being excluded.
You should check in the migrations that you are using which tags are being used. If the migrations use the tag "Drupal 7" then the command is:
drush migrate:status --tag="Drupal 7"

